# Comparing two statements of Chinese Remainder Theorem (Sun-Ze Theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Wikipedia states the Chinese Remainder Theorem as follows:

> Suppose $n_1, \dots, n_k$ are positive integers which are pairwise coprime. Then for any given sequence of integers $a_1, \dots, a_k$, there exists an integer $x$ such that $$ \begin{cases} x \equiv a_1 \operatorname{mod} n_1 \\
> x \equiv a_2 \operatorname{mod} n_2 \\ 
> \vdots \\
> x \equiv a_k \operatorname{mod} n_k \end{cases}$$
>   and all solutions $x$ are congruent mod $n_1n_2 \cdots n_k$.

My notes state the theorem as follows:

> Let $m$ and $n$ be relatively prime positive inters. Let $r$ and $s$ be integers such that $$rm + sn =1.$$ Then the function $$f: \mathbb{Z} / m \times \mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z} / mn$$ defined by $$f(x,y)= y \cdot rm + x \cdot sn$$ is a bijection.

How does the bijection give us that there always exists a solution to the system of modular congruences ?

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476528/chinese-remainder-theorem-interpretation?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of $f$ is $g:\mathbb Z_{mn}\to\mathbb Z_m\times\mathbb Z_n$ defined by $g(a\bmod mn)=(a\bmod m,a\bmod n)$. (Check this!)

If $a_1,a_2$ are given then, by the surjectivity of $g$, there is $x$ such that $g(x\bmod mn)=(a_1\bmod m,a_2\bmod n)$, and this means $x\equiv a_1\bmod m$ and $x\equiv a_2\bmod n$.

This generalizes as follows: if $n_1,\dots,n_k$ are coprime integers, then the map $g:\mathbb Z_{n_1\cdots n_k}\to\mathbb Z_{n_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb Z_{n_k}$ defined by $g(a\bmod n_1\cdots n_k)=(a\bmod n_1,\dots,a\bmod n_k)$ is an isomorphism (of rings) and now use again the surjectivity of $g$.